# CakePHP delete confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, confirmation

I have problem with Cake PHP delete javascript confirmation dialog.

I am using this code:

```
<td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete',
                                        array('controller' => 'RealEstate', 'action' => 'delete',$r['RealEstate']['id']),
                                        array('onclick'=>'return confirm(\"Are you sure?\");'))?> </td>
```

and this produce html:

```
<td><a onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure?\");' href="/cake1/RealEstate/delete/65">Delete</a> </td>
```

as  you can see this produce wrong Html.

How to fix this ?

**FIXED:
Problem was in back slashes \"Are you sure?\", just removed \ and this works well "Are you sure?"**

Comment: Yeah, no need to escape it there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED: Problem was in back slashes \"Are you sure?\", just removed \ and this works well "Are you sure?"**

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<?php 
     echo $this->Html->link('',array('controller'=>'Mycont','action'=>'deletepic',$id),
          array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete the image?'));
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array(
                               'controller'=>'RealEstate',
                               'action' => 'delete',
                                $r['RealEstate']['id']),
                                null, 
                                __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', 
                                $r['RealEstate']['id'])
 );
```

Comment: thanx.its working for me! you can use it with normal link too.           `echo $this->Html->link('DELETE', array(                                                              'action' => 'delete',$r['RealEstate']['id']),array(                         'class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-circle', 'escape' => false),__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?',$r['RealEstate']['name']));`